# how to configure XHProf for drupal 6 on windows?

Tags: drupal-6, xhprof

With the help of [Lorenzo Alberton](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/12/01/profiling-with-xhprof/) tutorial, i get XHProf installed for drupal 6 on linux server. Now i need to get it installed on windows but i found that XHProf cant be installed on windows. Additionally, at drupal.org [XHProf](http://drupal.org/project/XHProf), is available for drupal 7 onwards. If anyone has installed XHProf for drupal 6 on windows then please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been answered here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19193/how-to-configure-xhprof-for-drupal-6-on-windows
Just for the records, you do NOT need the Drupal module to use XHProf. You must download a compiled version for your apache (I'm using WAMP http://www.wampserver.com/en/, but can't remember where I got mine) and then enable it in php.ini. You can set the settings in the php.ini or trigger on demmand profiles. http://es2.php.net/xhprof

Comment: ya its answered http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19193/how-to-configure-xhprof-for-drupal-6-on-windows to me and I accepted the answer. thanks for help